# Getting an invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: oracle

This is my exact query which is erroring out

```
  alter table INDIL_MCAR drop constraint ABOB.INDI_MCAR_PK;
```

I m trying to remove the unique key constring from the table. It gives me the following error.

```
 ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Comment: I think that problem in `ABOB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prefix the constraint name... the table name yes, but not the constraint name. Remove the `ABOB.`:

```
alter table INDIL_MCAR drop constraint INDI_MCAR_PK;
```

Comment: Ok, now it gives me a non existent constrain error. However when I try to insert a duplicate record , it gives me a unique constraint(ABOB.INDI_MCAR_PK) violated.

Comment: What user are you logged in as? ABOB?  If not, then you'll need to prefix the table name: `alter table ABOB.INDIL_MCAR drop constraint INDI_MCAR_PK;`.  I would have expected a `table or view does not exist` error though...  Are you sure you got the right table name?

Comment: @slimsim - Based on the constraint name, I'm going to guess that it is a primary key.  Creating a primary key constraint by default creates a unique index of the same name that enforces the constraint.  Dropping the constraint alone does not drop the index.  So I'm guessing that you're getting an error because the index `indi_mcar_pk` still exists.  Assuming that is the case, you probably want to drop the index as well.

Comment: That is correct. I had to remove the index as well for it to work.

Comment: @JustinCave, if I don't misstake, in oracle 12 drop primary key constraint with unique index.

Comment: Actually, when dropping a pk constraint, sometimes the index gets dropped automatically, other times not, depending on whether the index existed before the primary key constraint was created or not.  To ensure that the index is always dropped when dropping the constraint, you can do: `alter table indil_mcar drop constraint indi_mcar_pk drop index`.